# is it possible to multiply two Gurobi linear expressions?

Tags: gurobi

I want to perform the following operation in Gurobi for Java:

[image]

Create the summatory terms is easy through `GRBLinExpr` but I donwt know hot to multiply those two `GRBLinExpr`. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can do this by adding intermediate variables for the sums, e.g. `sx = sum(x[i])` and `sy = sum(y[i])`; then you can replace the product of the linear expressions by the product `sx * sy`.

Comment: I don't see a way to assign a linear expression object to a variable.

Comment: You don't assign them, you add a constraint for the linear expressions.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see it.  In the example of your answer, sx and sy  are  Linear Expressions but how do I sx * sy out of a constraint?  Could you provide me an example?

Comment: No, sx and sy are new variables (GRBVar objects).